Python 3.10+: call async function within a property in a way that does not produce errors if that property is accessed in an async function
I have built a library that includes an ORM with the following use pattern:
class Model(SqlModel):
    columns = ('id', 'details', 'parent_id')
    parent: RelatedModel

Model.parent = belongs_to(Model, Model, 'parent_id')
...
def example(some_id, some_other_id):
    record = Model.find(some_id)
    if not record.parent:
        record.parent = Model.find(some_other_id)
        record.parent().save()

The most recent improvement is that related models accessed through the property are loaded on the first read of the property to avoid making library users write model.parent().reload() before the property is first accessed. E.g. parent_details = Model.find(some_id).parent.details.
An example implementation within a synchronous relation can be found here.
I replicated the whole SQL model, query builder, and ORM to use async. An example implementation within an asynchronous relation can be found here. The async use pattern is similar to the synchronous one:
class AsyncModel(AsyncSqlModel):
    columns = ('id', 'details', 'parent_id')
    parent: AsyncRelatedModel

AsyncModel.parent = async_belongs_to(AsyncModel, AsyncModel, 'parent_id')
...
async def example(some_id, some_other_id):
    record = await AsyncModel.find(some_id)
    if not record.parent:
        record.parent = await AsyncModel.find(some_other_id)
        await record.parent().save()

Reading the property within an async function (if not record.parent in the second pseudo-code example) results in RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop. I tried fixing this by replacing asyncio.run with asyncio.get_running_loop().run_until_complete, but it results in RuntimeError: This event loop is already running. I attempted running it in a new loop, but that results in RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running. Using the nest-asyncio package removed the RuntimeError but resulted in a ResourceWarning for an unclosed event loop, and the package repo was archived, so I need a better solution.
The advice from a similar question is to rewrite the function to be async, but this is not a plausible solution for a property.
Is there a solution that does not involve re-engineering the entire library use pattern or depending on an abandoned package?

Is Model.find a sync function or an async function?  It has to be one or the other; either it's declared with the async def syntax or it isn't.  In your example code, sometimes you put it in an await expression and sometimes you don't.  That will never work, because a sync function returns a value and an async function returns a coroutine.  I think you need to clarify that before your question can be addressed.

@PaulCornelius SqlModel.find is sync; AsyncSqlModel.find is async. Model subclasses one or the other -- there are two examples.

I'll edit the question to make it clearer and give the two subclasses different names.

Thanks for the clarification.  Another question: what do you mean by "property"?  It doesn't look like you are referring to a Python property (declared with the @property decorator), but perhaps you are.  Python properties cannot be declared async, so this is another aspect of your question that I don't understand.

@PaulCornelius yes, I mean a Python property. The belongs_to, etc relation helper functions return a Python property with an associated setter that allows the model object to access a relation object that handles all the ORM logic.

Sorry, but I guess I am just finding your question to be too cryptic.  Can you show us more of your code?  For example, the code that throws the Exception.  Perhaps more of AsyncModel.  In what you have presented, AsyncModel.parent is a class variable, not a @property associated with a single instance of AsyncModel.  You don't tell us what type of object is returned by find, but you seem to be saying that it has a @property named parent.  In your async example, does the Exception get thrown by the second call to AsyncModel.find or the first call?

Indeed - this is very hard to read - your property if it is really so, returns a very special object - which can be called, and has methods itself, and it is on that object that one answering your question has to know if they can be made asynchronous or not.
Moreover, you didn't put your main requirement that you commented in the linked question - that you'd like to be able to use the instance attribute without changing the lines where they are used, not even inserting an await where it is used.

@PaulCornelius I linked to the code repo in my question. Building an ORM is a fairly involved process -- there is a lot of code to sift through, and some who do might denounce my sorcerous ways, so I do not expect anyone to grokk it just for a Stack Overflow question.
